# RIA Services code generation files annoyance in VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, wcf-ria-services

This is a simple usability question regarding VS2010 in combination with using RIA Services. Every once in a while I have one of those pesky generated files open an VS keeps asking me whether to reload it. Is there way to get rid of this nuisance? Perhaps auto-reloading/auto-closing on change for a specific file pattern (*.g.cs)?

Not a big thing, I know. But it annoys me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can allow reloading of all files when it changes. From `Tools > Options...`, you can set the top three settings as shown in the image below.

By disallowing editing of read-only files, you will not accidentally edit the *.g.cs files, causing VS to panic even more.

[image: Visual Studio options dialog]